# Keycloak and external Infinispan and Console -> throws error while marshaling

Tags: keycloak, infinispan, distributed-caching

I have configured setup based on example from https://github.com/thomasdarimont/keycloak-project-example/tree/main/deployments/local/clusterx/haproxy-external-ispn-database which in my case works on local kubernetes (minikube).

My keycloak (quarkus version 20.0.3) infinispan subsystem looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<infinispan
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:13.0 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-13.0.xsd"
        xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:13.0">

    <cache-container name="keycloak">
        <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>

        <local-cache-configuration name="local-cache-cfg">
            <encoding>
                <key media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
                <value media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
            </encoding>
        </local-cache-configuration>

        <local-cache name="realms" configuration="local-cache-cfg">
            <memory max-count="10000"/>
        </local-cache>

        <local-cache name="users" configuration="local-cache-cfg">
            <memory max-count="10000"/>
        </local-cache>


        <local-cache name="keys" configuration="local-cache-cfg">
            <expiration max-idle="3600000"/>
            <memory max-count="1000"/>
        </local-cache>

        <local-cache name="authorization" configuration="local-cache-cfg">
            <memory max-count="10000"/>
        </local-cache>

        <distributed-cache name="authenticationSessions" owners="2">
            <expiration lifespan="-1"/>
        </distributed-cache>

        <distributed-cache name="sessions" owners="2">
            <expiration lifespan="-1"/>
            <remote-store xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:store:remote:13.0"
                          cache="sessions"
                          fetch-state="false"
                          purge="false"
                          preload="false"
                          shared="true"
                          segmented="false"
                          connect-timeout="${env.KEYCLOAK_REMOTE_ISPN_CONN_TIMEOUT:2000}"
                          raw-values="true"
                          marshaller="org.keycloak.cluster.infinispan.KeycloakHotRodMarshallerFactory">
                <remote-server host="external-infinispan" port="${infinispan.bind.port:8766}"/>

                <security>
                    <authentication>
                        <digest username="${env.KEYCLOAK_REMOTE_ISPN_USERNAME:keycloak}"
                                password="${env.KEYCLOAK_REMOTE_ISPN_PASSWORD:password}"
                                realm="default"/>
                    </authentication>
                    <encryption>
                        <truststore filename="${env.KEYCLOAK_REMOTE_ISPN_TRUSTSTORE_PATH:/opt/keycloak/conf/ispn-truststore.jks}"
                                    password="${env.KEYCLOAK_REMOTE_ISPN_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD:password}"
                                    type="${env.KEYCLOAK_REMOTE_ISPN_TRUSTSTORE_TYPE:JKS}"/>
                    </encryption>
                </security>
            </remote-store>
        </distributed-cache>

        <distributed-cache name="clientSessions" owners="2">
            <expiration lifespan="-1"/>
            <remote-store xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:store:remote:13.0"
                          cache="clientSessions"
                          fetch-state="false"
                          purge="false"
                          preload="false"
                          shared="true"
                          segmented="false"
                          connect-timeout="${env.KEYCLOAK_REMOTE_ISPN_CONN_TIMEOUT:2000}"
                          raw-values="true"
                          marshaller="org.keycloak.cluster.infinispan.KeycloakHotRodMarshallerFactory">
                <remote-server host="external-infinispan" port="${infinispan.bind.port:8766}"/>
                <security>
                    <authentication>
                        <digest username="${env.KEYCLOAK_REMOTE_ISPN_USERNAME:keycloak}"
                                password="${env.KEYCLOAK_REMOTE_ISPN_PASSWORD:password}"
                                realm="default"/>
                    </authentication>
                    <encryption>
                        <truststore filename="${env.KEYCLOAK_REMOTE_ISPN_TRUSTSTORE_PATH:/opt/keycloak/conf/ispn-truststore.jks}"
                                    password="${env.KEYCLOAK_REMOTE_ISPN_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD:password}"
                                    type="${env.KEYCLOAK_REMOTE_ISPN_TRUSTSTORE_TYPE:JKS}"/>
                    </encryption>
                </security>
            </remote-store>
        </distributed-cache>

        <distributed-cache name="offlineSessions" owners="2">
            <expiration lifespan="-1"/>
            <remote-store xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:store:remote:13.0"
                          cache="offlineSessions"
                          fetch-state="false"
                          purge="false"
                          preload="false"
                          shared="true"
                          segmented="false"
                          connect-timeout="${env.KEYCLOAK_REMOTE_ISPN_CONN_TIMEOUT:2000}"
                          raw-values="true"
                          marshaller="org.keycloak.cluster.infinispan.KeycloakHotRodMarshallerFactory">
                <remote-server host="external-infinispan" port="${infinispan.bind.port:8766}"/>
                <security>
                    <authentication>
                        <digest username="${env.KEYCLOAK_REMOTE_ISPN_USERNAME:keycloak}"
                                password="${env.KEYCLOAK_REMOTE_ISPN_PASSWORD:password}"
                                realm="default"/>
                    </authentication>
                    <encryption>
                        <truststore filename="${env.KEYCLOAK_REMOTE_ISPN_TRUSTSTORE_PATH:/opt/keycloak/conf/ispn-truststore.jks}"
                                    password="${env.KEYCLOAK_REMOTE_ISPN_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD:password}"
                                    type="${env.KEYCLOAK_REMOTE_ISPN_TRUSTSTORE_TYPE:JKS}"/>
                    </encryption>
                </security>
            </remote-store>
        </distributed-cache>

        <distributed-cache name="offlineClientSessions" owners="2">
            <expiration lifespan="-1"/>
            <remote-store xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:store:remote:13.0"
                          cache="offlineClientSessions"
                          fetch-state="false"
                          purge="false"
                          preload="false"
                          shared="true"
                          segmented="false"
                          connect-timeout="${env.KEYCLOAK_REMOTE_ISPN_CONN_TIMEOUT:2000}"
                          raw-values="true"
                          marshaller="org.keycloak.cluster.infinispan.KeycloakHotRodMarshallerFactory">
                <remote-server host="external-infinispan" port="${infinispan.bind.port:8766}"/>
                <security>
                    <authentication>
                        <digest username="${env.KEYCLOAK_REMOTE_ISPN_USERNAME:keycloak}"
                                password="${env.KEYCLOAK_REMOTE_ISPN_PASSWORD:password}"
                                realm="default"/>
                    </authentication>
                    <encryption>
                        <truststore filename="${env.KEYCLOAK_REMOTE_ISPN_TRUSTSTORE_PATH:/opt/keycloak/conf/ispn-truststore.jks}"
                                    password="${env.KEYCLOAK_REMOTE_ISPN_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD:password}"
                                    type="${env.KEYCLOAK_REMOTE_ISPN_TRUSTSTORE_TYPE:JKS}"/>
                    </encryption>
                </security>
            </remote-store>
        </distributed-cache>

        <distributed-cache name="loginFailures" owners="2">
            <expiration lifespan="-1"/>
            <remote-store xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:store:remote:13.0"
                          cache="loginFailures"
                          fetch-state="false"
                          purge="false"
                          preload="false"
                          shared="true"
                          segmented="false"
                          connect-timeout="${env.KEYCLOAK_REMOTE_ISPN_CONN_TIMEOUT:2000}"
                          raw-values="true"
                          marshaller="org.keycloak.cluster.infinispan.KeycloakHotRodMarshallerFactory">
                <remote-server host="external-infinispan" port="${infinispan.bind.port:8766}"/>
                <security>
                    <authentication>
                        <digest username="${env.KEYCLOAK_REMOTE_ISPN_USERNAME:keycloak}"
                                password="${env.KEYCLOAK_REMOTE_ISPN_PASSWORD:password}"
                                realm="default"/>
                    </authentication>
                    <encryption>
                        <truststore filename="${env.KEYCLOAK_REMOTE_ISPN_TRUSTSTORE_PATH:/opt/keycloak/conf/ispn-truststore.jks}"
                                    password="${env.KEYCLOAK_REMOTE_ISPN_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD:password}"
                                    type="${env.KEYCLOAK_REMOTE_ISPN_TRUSTSTORE_TYPE:JKS}"/>
                    </encryption>
                </security>
            </remote-store>
        </distributed-cache>

        <distributed-cache name="actionTokens" owners="2">
            <encoding>
                <key media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
                <value media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
            </encoding>
            <expiration max-idle="-1" lifespan="-1" interval="300000"/>
            <memory max-count="-1"/>
            <remote-store cache="actionTokens" xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:store:remote:13.0"
                          fetch-state="false"
                          purge="false"
                          preload="false"
                          shared="true"
                          segmented="false"
                          connect-timeout="${env.KEYCLOAK_REMOTE_ISPN_CONN_TIMEOUT:2000}"
                          raw-values="true"
                          marshaller="org.keycloak.cluster.infinispan.KeycloakHotRodMarshallerFactory">
                <remote-server host="external-infinispan" port="${infinispan.bind.port:8766}"/>
                <security>
                    <authentication>
                        <digest username="${env.KEYCLOAK_REMOTE_ISPN_USERNAME:keycloak}"
                                password="${env.KEYCLOAK_REMOTE_ISPN_PASSWORD:password}"
                                realm="default"/>
                    </authentication>
                    <encryption>
                        <truststore filename="${env.KEYCLOAK_REMOTE_ISPN_TRUSTSTORE_PATH:/opt/keycloak/conf/ispn-truststore.jks}"
                                    password="${env.KEYCLOAK_REMOTE_ISPN_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD:password}"
                                    type="${env.KEYCLOAK_REMOTE_ISPN_TRUSTSTORE_TYPE:JKS}"/>
                    </encryption>
                </security>
            </remote-store>
        </distributed-cache>

        <replicated-cache name="work">
            <expiration lifespan="-1"/>
        </replicated-cache>
    </cache-container>
</infinispan>
```

and my external infinispan (version 14.0.7-Final-2) configuration looks like below:

```
<infinispan
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:13.0"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:13.0 https://infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-13.0.xsd urn:infinispan:server:13.0 https://infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-server-13.0.xsd">

    <!-- TODO configure JGROUPS tcp Stack with encryption -->

    <!-- see https://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/13.0/configdocs/infinispan-config-13.0.html -->


    <cache-container name="default" statistics="true">

        <serialization marshaller="org.infinispan.jboss.marshalling.commons.GenericJBossMarshaller">
            <allow-list>
                <class>org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.changes.SessionEntityWrapper</class>
                <regex>org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.changes.*</regex>
            </allow-list>
        </serialization> 

        <!-- TODO configure custom jgroups stack: +auth +encryption -->
        <transport
                cluster="${infinispan.cluster.name:REMOTE}"
                stack="${infinispan.cluster.stack:kubernetes}"
                node-name="${infinispan.node.name:}"/>

        <replicated-cache-configuration name="replicated-cache-cfg"
                                        xmlns:jdbc="urn:infinispan:config:store:jdbc:13.0"
                                        mode="SYNC"
                                        statistics="true"
                                        segments="256"
                                        unreliable-return-values="false">
           <encoding>
                <key media-type="application/x-jboss-marshalling"/>
                <value media-type="application/x-jboss-marshalling"/>
            </encoding>
            <transaction mode="NON_XA"
                         locking="OPTIMISTIC"/>
            <persistence passivation="false">
                <jdbc:string-keyed-jdbc-store fetch-state="false" shared="true" preload="false">
                    <jdbc:data-source jndi-url="jdbc/datasource"/>
                    <jdbc:string-keyed-table drop-on-exit="false" create-on-start="true" prefix="ispn">
                        <jdbc:id-column name="id" type="VARCHAR(255)"/>
                        <jdbc:data-column name="data" type="bytea"/>
                        <jdbc:timestamp-column name="ts" type="BIGINT"/>
                        <jdbc:segment-column name="seg" type="INT"/>
                    </jdbc:string-keyed-table>
                </jdbc:string-keyed-jdbc-store>
            </persistence>
        </replicated-cache-configuration>

        <distributed-cache-configuration name="distributed-cache-cfg"
                                         xmlns:jdbc="urn:infinispan:config:store:jdbc:13.0"
                                         mode="SYNC"
                                         owners="2"
                                         remote-timeout="60000"
                                         statistics="true"
                                         segments="256"
                                         unreliable-return-values="false">

            <encoding>
                <key media-type="application/x-jboss-marshalling"/>
                <value media-type="application/x-jboss-marshalling"/>
            </encoding>
            <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"
                     striping="false"
                     acquire-timeout="10000"
                     concurrency-level="32"/>

            <transaction mode="NON_XA"
                         locking="OPTIMISTIC"/>

            <expiration lifespan="-1"
                        max-idle="-1"
                        interval="60000" />

            <memory max-count="-1" when-full="NONE" storage="HEAP"/>

            <partition-handling when-split="ALLOW_READ_WRITES" />

            <persistence passivation="false">
                <jdbc:string-keyed-jdbc-store fetch-state="false" shared="true" preload="false">
                    <jdbc:data-source jndi-url="jdbc/datasource"/>
                    <jdbc:string-keyed-table drop-on-exit="false" create-on-start="true" prefix="ispn">
                        <jdbc:id-column name="id" type="VARCHAR(255)"/>
                        <jdbc:data-column name="data" type="bytea"/>
                        <jdbc:timestamp-column name="ts" type="BIGINT"/>
                        <jdbc:segment-column name="seg" type="INT"/>
                    </jdbc:string-keyed-table>
                </jdbc:string-keyed-jdbc-store>
            </persistence>


            <state-transfer enabled="true"
                            timeout="240000"
                            chunk-size="240000"
                            await-initial-transfer="true"/>
        </distributed-cache-configuration>

<!--        <replicated-cache name="work" configuration="replicated-cache-cfg">-->
<!--        </replicated-cache>-->

        <distributed-cache name="sessions" configuration="distributed-cache-cfg">
        </distributed-cache>

        <distributed-cache name="authenticationSessions" configuration="distributed-cache-cfg">
        </distributed-cache>

        <distributed-cache name="offlineSessions" configuration="distributed-cache-cfg">
        </distributed-cache>

        <distributed-cache name="clientSessions" configuration="distributed-cache-cfg">
        </distributed-cache>

        <distributed-cache name="offlineClientSessions" configuration="distributed-cache-cfg">
        </distributed-cache>

        <distributed-cache name="loginFailures" configuration="distributed-cache-cfg">
        </distributed-cache>

        <distributed-cache name="actionTokens" configuration="distributed-cache-cfg">
            <memory max-count="-1">
            </memory>
            <expiration interval="300000" max-idle="-1"/>
        </distributed-cache>

<!--        <security>-->
<!--            <authorization>-->
<!--                <roles>-->
<!--                    <role name="supervisor" permissions="READ WRITE EXEC CREATE"/>-->
<!--                </roles>-->
<!--            </authorization>-->
<!--        </security>-->
    </cache-container>

    <!-- https://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/13.0/configdocs/infinispan-server-13.0.html# -->
    <server xmlns="urn:infinispan:server:13.0">

        <interfaces>
            <interface name="public">
                <!-- we bind to the eth0 interface instead of a specific ip address to ease access -->
                <!--                <inet-address value="${infinispan.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>-->
                <match-interface value="eth0"/>
                <!-- or use any-address element -->
            </interface>
        </interfaces>

        <socket-bindings default-interface="public" port-offset="${infinispan.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
            <socket-binding name="default" port="${infinispan.bind.port:11222}"/>
<!--            <socket-binding name="memcached" port="11221"/>-->
        </socket-bindings>

        <security>
            <security-realms>
                <security-realm name="default">
                    <!--  Uncomment to enable TLS on the realm  -->
                    <server-identities>
                        <ssl>
                            <keystore path="ispn-server.jks" relative-to="infinispan.server.config.path"
                                      password="password" alias="server" key-password="password"
                                      generate-self-signed-certificate-host="localhost"/>
                        </ssl>
                    </server-identities>
                    <properties-realm groups-attribute="Roles">
                        <user-properties path="users.properties" relative-to="infinispan.server.config.path"
                                         plain-text="true"/>
                        <group-properties path="groups.properties" relative-to="infinispan.server.config.path"/>
                    </properties-realm>
                </security-realm>
            </security-realms>
        </security>


        <data-sources>
            <data-source name="KeycloakDS" jndi-name="jdbc/datasource" statistics="true">
                <connection-factory driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
                                    username="postgres"
                                    password="password"
                                    url="jdbc:postgresql://db-address/postgres"
                                    new-connection-sql="SELECT 1" transaction-isolation="READ_COMMITTED">
                </connection-factory>
                <connection-pool initial-size="1" max-size="10"  min-size="3" background-validation="1000" idle-removal="1" blocking-timeout="1000" leak-detection="10000"/>
            </data-source>
        </data-sources>

        <!-- see https://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/13.0/configdocs/infinispan-server-13.0.html#endpoints -->
        <endpoints>
            <endpoint socket-binding="default" security-realm="default">
                <hotrod-connector name="hotrod" security-realm="default"/>
                <rest-connector>
                    <authentication mechanisms="BASIC"/>
                </rest-connector>
            </endpoint>
        </endpoints>
    </server>

</infinispan>
```

I can see that almost all functionalities seems to work pretty well, but when I navigate to infinispan console **Global Statistics** and then click cache which has entries then infinispan throws exception:

```
[org.infinispan.rest.stream.CacheChunkedStream] Error encountered while streaming cache chunk org.infinispan.commons.dataconversion.EncodingException: ISPN000495: JBossMarshallingTranscoder encountered error transcoding content
 at org.infinispan.jboss.marshalling.dataconversion.JBossMarshallingTranscoder.unmarshall(JBossMarshallingTranscoder.java:84)
 at org.infinispan.jboss.marshalling.dataconversion.JBossMarshallingTranscoder.doTranscode(JBossMarshallingTranscoder.java:59)
 at org.infinispan.commons.dataconversion.AbstractTranscoder.transcode(AbstractTranscoder.java:69)
 at org.infinispan.encoding.DataConversion.fromStorage(DataConversion.java:222)
 at org.infinispan.cache.impl.EncoderEntryMapper.apply(EncoderEntryMapper.java:63)
 at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FlowableMap.java:64)
 at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableRepeatUntil$RepeatSubscriber.onNext(FlowableRepeatUntil.java:67)
 at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableDoOnLifecycle$SubscriptionLambdaSubscriber.onNext(FlowableDoOnLifecycle.java:80)
 at io.reactivex.rxjava3.processors.UnicastProcessor.drainRegular(UnicastProcessor.java:309)
 at io.reactivex.rxjava3.processors.UnicastProcessor.drain(UnicastProcessor.java:384)
 at io.reactivex.rxjava3.processors.UnicastProcessor.onNext(UnicastProcessor.java:444)
 at org.infinispan.reactive.publisher.impl.InnerPublisherSubscription$InnerPublisherSubscriptionBuilder$1.doOnValue(InnerPublisherSubscription.java:81)
 at org.infinispan.reactive.publisher.impl.InnerPublisherSubscription.lambda$accept$0(InnerPublisherSubscription.java:228)
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:863)
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:841)
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:510)
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2147)
 at org.infinispan.reactive.publisher.impl.PublisherHandler$PublisherState.prepareResponse(PublisherHandler.java:438)
 at org.infinispan.reactive.publisher.impl.PublisherHandler$PublisherState.onComplete(PublisherHandler.java:301)
 at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FlowableConcatMap.java:258)
 at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableConcatMap$BaseConcatMapSubscriber.onComplete(FlowableConcatMap.java:165)
 at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableDoFinally$DoFinallySubscriber.onComplete(FlowableDoFinally.java:96)
 at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FlowableConcatMap.java:258)
 at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableConcatMap$BaseConcatMapSubscriber.innerComplete(FlowableConcatMap.java:171)
 at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onComplete(FlowableConcatMap.java:587)
 at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.subscribers.SinglePostCompleteSubscriber.complete(SinglePostCompleteSubscriber.java:82)
 at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableConcatWithSingle$ConcatWithSubscriber.onSuccess(FlowableConcatWithSingle.java:81)
 at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.single.SingleFromSupplier.subscribeActual(SingleFromSupplier.java:60)
 at io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Single.subscribe(Single.java:4855)
 at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableConcatWithSingle$ConcatWithSubscriber.onComplete(FlowableConcatWithSingle.java:89)
 at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.subscribers.BasicFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(BasicFuseableSubscriber.java:120)
 at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.onComplete(FlowableConcatArray.java:113)
 at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.subscribers.BasicFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(BasicFuseableSubscriber.java:120)
 at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableUsing$UsingSubscriber.onComplete(FlowableUsing.java:144)
 at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableObserveOn$BaseObserveOnSubscriber.checkTerminated(FlowableObserveOn.java:217)
 at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.runAsync(FlowableObserveOn.java:396)
 at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableObserveOn$BaseObserveOnSubscriber.run(FlowableObserveOn.java:178)
 at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.schedulers.ExecutorScheduler$ExecutorWorker$BooleanRunnable.run(ExecutorScheduler.java:324)
 at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.schedulers.ExecutorScheduler$ExecutorWorker.runEager(ExecutorScheduler.java:289)
 at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.schedulers.ExecutorScheduler$ExecutorWorker.run(ExecutorScheduler.java:250)
 at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174)
 at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167)
 at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
 at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:403)
 at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
 at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
 at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.changes.SessionEntityWrapper
 at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:587)
 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
 at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
 at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractClassResolver.loadClass(AbstractClassResolver.java:129)
 at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractClassResolver.resolveClass(AbstractClassResolver.java:110)
 at org.infinispan.jboss.marshalling.commons.CheckedClassResolver.resolveClass(CheckedClassResolver.java:31)
.
.
.
```

Seems like this **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.changes.SessionEntityWrapper** directly says that infinispan does not have such class.

Do you know how to fix that? Should I try with different version of Infinispan?

Comment: Try removing `<serialization>` and `<encoding>` elements from Infinispan server configuration.

Comment: Indeed - it fixed the issue, however I see warning that I cannot decode data from keycloak (HotRod client): **This cache either has no encoding configuration or uses an encoding that the console does not support. You must use Hot Rod clients to perform read and write operations on this cache.**. Is it possible to enable encoding? Documentation is a bit blurry how to do that.

Comment: Yes. You can use your original configuration but it requires installing a JAR in the Infinispan server with the Keycloak data objects and their externalizer implementation (assuming Keycloak uses JBoss Marshalling).

Comment: Then understand I should follow this instruction: https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/encoding/encoding.html#adding-jars-server-classpath_storage-formats? If so, then I should put jar which contains org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.changes.SessionEntityWrapper to server/lib folder on infinispan side and thats it? What do you mean by **externalizer implementation**?

Comment: Yes, in theory (x2). If I'm not mistaken, the Jboss Marshalling Externalizer interface tells, how to convert the object to byte[] and vice-versa. Example: https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan/blob/main/jboss-marshalling/src/test/java/org/infinispan/jboss/marshalling/PojoWithJBossExternalize.java#L48

Answer (score 0):

If anyone faces similiar issues below are things which I had to do to make it works.

According to **pruivo** hints I applied following changes:

1. Added keycloak files to /opt/infinispan/server/lib folder of infinispan image.

```
FROM quay.io/infinispan/server:14.0

COPY /org.jboss.marshalling.jboss-marshalling-osgi-2.1.1.Final.jar /opt/infinispan/server/lib
COPY /org.keycloak.keycloak-admin-ui-21.0.1.jar /opt/infinispan/server/lib
COPY /org.keycloak.keycloak-authz-policy-common-21.0.1.jar /opt/infinispan/server/lib
COPY /org.keycloak.keycloak-common-21.0.1.jar /opt/infinispan/server/lib
COPY /org.keycloak.keycloak-config-api-21.0.1.jar /opt/infinispan/server/lib
COPY /org.keycloak.keycloak-core-21.0.1.jar /opt/infinispan/server/lib
COPY /org.keycloak.keycloak-crypto-default-21.0.1.jar /opt/infinispan/server/lib
COPY /org.keycloak.keycloak-crypto-fips1402-21.0.1.jar /opt/infinispan/server/lib
COPY /org.keycloak.keycloak-js-adapter-21.0.1.jar /opt/infinispan/server/lib
COPY /org.keycloak.keycloak-kerberos-federation-21.0.1.jar /opt/infinispan/server/lib
COPY /org.keycloak.keycloak-ldap-federation-21.0.1.jar /opt/infinispan/server/lib
COPY /org.keycloak.keycloak-model-infinispan-21.0.1.jar /opt/infinispan/server/lib
COPY /org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa-21.0.1.jar /opt/infinispan/server/lib
COPY /org.keycloak.keycloak-model-legacy-21.0.1.jar /opt/infinispan/server/lib
COPY /org.keycloak.keycloak-model-legacy-private-21.0.1.jar /opt/infinispan/server/lib
COPY /org.keycloak.keycloak-model-legacy-services-21.0.1.jar /opt/infinispan/server/lib
COPY /org.keycloak.keycloak-model-map-21.0.1.jar /opt/infinispan/server/lib
COPY /org.keycloak.keycloak-model-map-file-21.0.1.jar /opt/infinispan/server/lib
COPY /org.keycloak.keycloak-model-map-hot-rod-21.0.1.jar /opt/infinispan/server/lib
COPY /org.keycloak.keycloak-model-map-jpa-21.0.1.jar /opt/infinispan/server/lib
COPY /org.keycloak.keycloak-rest-admin-ui-ext-21.0.1.jar /opt/infinispan/server/lib
COPY /org.keycloak.keycloak-saml-core-21.0.1.jar /opt/infinispan/server/lib
COPY /org.keycloak.keycloak-saml-core-public-21.0.1.jar /opt/infinispan/server/lib
COPY /org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-21.0.1.jar /opt/infinispan/server/lib
COPY /org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private-21.0.1.jar /opt/infinispan/server/lib
COPY /org.keycloak.keycloak-services-21.0.1.jar /opt/infinispan/server/lib
COPY /org.keycloak.keycloak-sssd-federation-21.0.1.jar /opt/infinispan/server/lib
COPY /org.keycloak.keycloak-themes-21.0.1.jar /opt/infinispan/server/lib

COPY /common.sh /opt/infinispan/bin

USER 0

RUN true \
  && microdnf clean all \
  && microdnf install shadow-utils \
  && microdnf update --nodocs \
  && adduser ispn \
  && microdnf remove shadow-utils \
  && microdnf clean all

RUN chown -R ispn:0 /opt/infinispan

RUN curl https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-42.5.2.jar --output /opt/infinispan/lib/postgresql-42.5.2.jar

USER ispn

CMD [ "-c", "infinispan-keycloak.xml" ]
ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/infinispan/bin/server.sh" ]
```

2. Infinispan deployment

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: acme-ispn-service-headless
  namespace: keycloak
  labels:
    app: acme-ispn-service-headless
spec:
  ports:
    - name: jgroups
      port: 7800
      targetPort: 7800
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: acme-ispn
  type: ClusterIP
  clusterIP: None
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: acme-ispn
  namespace: keycloak
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: acme-ispn
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: acme-ispn
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: config-volume
        configMap:
          name: kc-config
      containers:
      - name: acme-ispn
        image: created-image
        command: ["/opt/infinispan/bin/server.sh", "-c", "infinispan-keycloak-database.xml"]
        volumeMounts:
          - name: config-volume
            mountPath: /opt/infinispan/server/conf/infinispan-keycloak-database.xml
            subPath: infinispan-keycloak-database.xml
          - name: config-volume
            mountPath: /opt/infinispan/server/conf/ispn-server.jks
            subPath: ispn-server.jks
          - name: config-volume
            mountPath: /opt/infinispan/server/conf/users.properties
            subPath: users.properties
          - name: config-volume
            mountPath: /opt/infinispan/server/conf/log4j2.xml
            subPath: log4j2.xml
          - name: config-volume
            mountPath: /opt/infinispan/bin/common.sh
            subPath: common.sh
        ports:
        - name: jgroups
          containerPort: 7600
        - name: console  
          containerPort: 11222
        env:
          - name: jgroups.dns.query
            value: acme-ispn-service-headless.keycloak.svc.cluster.local
```

What is important file log4j2.xml specifices log level of infinispan and file common.sh contains java arguments parameter which I had to add extra --add-opens parameters like below:

```
    if [ "$JAVA_VERSION" -ge 17 ]; then
        # Enable export for LDAP (needed for JDK 17+)
        PREPEND_JAVA_OPTS="$PREPEND_JAVA_OPTS --add-exports java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap=ALL-UNNAMED"
        PREPEND_JAVA_OPTS="$PREPEND_JAVA_OPTS --add-opens java.base/java.base=ALL-UNNAMED"
        PREPEND_JAVA_OPTS="$PREPEND_JAVA_OPTS --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED"
        PREPEND_JAVA_OPTS="$PREPEND_JAVA_OPTS --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED"
        PREPEND_JAVA_OPTS="$PREPEND_JAVA_OPTS --add-opens java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED"
        PREPEND_JAVA_OPTS="$PREPEND_JAVA_OPTS --add-opens java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED"
    fi
```

which is fix for jdk 17 and above.

I also had to introduce

```
        <serialization marshaller="org.infinispan.jboss.marshalling.commons.GenericJBossMarshaller">
            <allow-list>
                <regex>org.keycloak.*</regex>
                <regex>java.util.*</regex>
            </allow-list>
        </serialization>
```

to external infinispan configurations.

3. Dockerfile for keycloak is not changed and the same is the same as https://github.com/thomasdarimont/keycloak-project-example/blob/main/deployments/local/clusterx/keycloakx/Dockerfile.
4. However deployment for keycloak looks like below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: keycloak-service
  namespace: keycloak
  labels:
    app: keycloak-service
spec:
  ports:
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: 8443
    - name: jgroups
      port: 7800
      targetPort: 7800
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: keycloak-deployment
  type: ClusterIP
  clusterIP: None
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: keycloak-deployment
  namespace: keycloak
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keycloak-deployment
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak-deployment
    spec:
      containers:
        - name:  keycloak
          image: created-image
          command: ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh", "start"]
          args: [" --auto-build",  "--cache-stack=kubernetes", "--log-level=debug", "--cache-config-file=cache-ispn-remote.xml"]
          volumeMounts:
            - name: certs
              mountPath: "/etc/certs"
              readOnly: true
            - name: config-volume
              mountPath:  /opt/keycloak/conf/cache-ispn-remote.xml 
              subPath: cache-ispn-remote.xml
          env:
            - name: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN
              value: "adminname"
            - name: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD
              value: "admpassword"
            - name: KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_FILE
              value: "/etc/certs/tls.crt"
            - name: KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_KEY_FILE
              value: "/etc/certs/tls.key"
            - name: KC_HEALTH_ENABLED
              value: "true"
            - name: KC_METRICS_ENABLED
              value: "true"
            - name: KC_HOSTNAME
              value: kc.localtest.me
            - name: KC_PROXY
              value: "edge"
            - name: KC_DB
              value: postgres
            - name: KC_DB_URL
              value: "jdbc:postgresql://keycloak-db-postgresql-ha-postgresql/postgres"
            - name: KC_DB_USERNAME
              value: "postgres"
            - name: KC_DB_PASSWORD
              value: some_pass
            - name: KC_DB_SCHEMA
              value: public
            - name: jgroups.dns.query
              value: keycloak-service.keycloak.svc.cluster.local
          ports:
            - name: jgroups
              containerPort: 7600
            - name: https
              containerPort: 8443
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              scheme: HTTPS
              path: /health/ready
              port: 8443
            initialDelaySeconds: 60
            periodSeconds: 1
      volumes:
        - name: certs
          secret:
            secretName: auth-tls-secret
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: kc-config
```

Seems like all above steps makes KC works well with external infinispan.

One more thing which is riddle for me is infinispan statistics:
[image]

I can see something like that - total number of entries is 3, but when I navigate to cache to preview it I can see only two entries:

Sessions:
[image]

clientSessions:
[image]

Is it correct?
Why cannot I see e.g. number of entries?
Also when I intentianally entered bad credentials I suspect I can observe loginFailure cache, but this is not happen at all.